# unregisterListener is not working on button click event

Tags: android, events, listener

Here is my code. I am new to android development. I called `registerListener` on button click event. It starts getting data from accelerometer but when I call `unregisterListener` from another button click, it is not working.

```
public void startButton(View view){
    findViewById(R.id.stop).setEnabled(true);
    findViewById(R.id.start).setEnabled(false);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    selsensors = intent.getStringExtra(SensorsList.SELECTED_SENSORS);
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    senList = mSensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL);
    mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer,    mSensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event){
    if(event.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER){
        ax = event.values[0];
        ay = event.values[1];
        az = event.values[2];
        Toast.makeText(this, "X: "+ax+"\nY: "+ay+"\nZ: "+az, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
public void stopButton(View view){
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    this.finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the unregister function which has the sensor as parameter? Furthermore, are you sure you are not calling the deprecated unregister functions? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html

```
mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer,    mSensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this, mAccelerometer);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, i think it is working since i was using toast to display accelerometer values so after executing the unregisterListener the remaining messages are being diplayed by toast.I got the idea when i saw the logcat.